# When Heine-Borel theorem applies

Tags: real-analysis

Question: What condition of the Heine-Borel Theorem does this not meet?

Consider $\mathbb Q$ with metric $d(p,q) = |p-q|$, and
$$
E =  \{q : 2 < p^2 < 3\}.
$$

We can show that $E$ is closed and bounded and $E$ is not compact.

$E$ is a subset of $\mathbb R^1$ and euclidean space with the appropriate metric.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To apply Heine-Borel, you need your space to be complete. But $\mathbb Q$ isn't.

Note that, as a subset of $\mathbb R$, your set $E$ is not closed.